# c# reading a pdf from request body and writing to file

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I want to read a pdf from the request body and write it to a file.

Basically the raw request body looks something like this:

```
%PDF-1.7
4 0 obj
(Identity)
endobj
5 0 obj
(Adobe)
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 33775
/Length1 81256
/Type /Stream
>>
stream
...
%%EOF
```

I wont post the whole request body as it is quite big.

In my code I read it as the following

```
 var content = (HttpContent)new StreamContent(Request.Body);
 var bytes =  await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Then write the bytes to a file

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
{
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

However, the text in that pdf is not getting written to the file. It's just a blank PDF. The pdf is suppose to show the text "test".

EDIT:

New findings.

When testing my code through postman, I found using the postman body `binary` section to upload a pdf works just fine but when sending the same pdf raw content through the postman body `raw` section it does not work. Is it because some information is loss when copying the raw content of the pdf directly to postman?

Comment: Can you try logging how many bytes are read from the `HttpContent` and written to disk? Maybe comparing that with the length of bytes sent in the request body will help find an issue, or rule something out.

Comment: The `var bytes` returns `55628` and the bytes written to disk is also `55628`

Comment: I updated my original post with some findings

Comment: Have you compared not just the lengths but also the contents of the files in question?

Comment: What do you mean comparing the contents of the file?